# Webpack 4 disable minification but retain-tree shaking

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, uglifyjs, terser

I am looking for a way of disabling minification of files but retaining tree-shaking.

Terser Plugin takes care of tree shaking but apparently only when minimize is set true, and in Webpack production mode.

```
optimization: {
  minimize: true
}
```

Where `minimize` is set to `false`, the unminified file does not shake out unused functions.

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    config.optimization.usedExports = true
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map'
    config.optimization.minimize = true
    config.optimization.minimizer =  [new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
        terserOptions: {
            compress: {
                defaults: false,
                unused: true
            },
            mangle: false,
            format: {
                comments: 'all'
            }
        }
    })]
```

This will be works but still does remove whitespace.

Answer (score -3):

```
optimization: {
  minimize: false,
  usedExports: true,
}
```

You should be able to use webpack's existing [optimization.usedExports](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationusedexports) configuration to achieve tree shaking for your compilation.